# How to align multiple camera images using opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

Imagine someone taking a burst shot from camera, he will be having multiple images, but since no tripod or stand was used, images taken will be slightly different.

How can I align them such that they overlay neatly and crop out the edges

I have searched a lot, but most of the solutions were either making a 3D reconstruction or using matlab.

e.g. https://github.com/royshil/SfM-Toy-Library

Since I'm very new to openCV, I will prefer a easy to implement solution

I have generated many datasets by manually rotating and cropping images in MSPaint but any link containing corresponding datasets(slightly rotated and translated images) will also be helpful.

EDIT:I found a solution here
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/24809/Image-Alignment-Algorithms
which gives close approximations to rotation and translation vectors.

How can I do better than this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "better" (accuracy, speed, low memory requirements, etc). One classic approach is to align each frame #i (with i>2) with the first frame, as follows:

1. Local feature detection, for instance via SIFT or SURF ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html))
2. Descriptor extraction ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_extractors.html))
3. Descriptor matching ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html))
4. Alignment estimation via perspective transformation ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography))
5. Transform image #i to match image 1 using the estimated transformation ([link](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=warpperspective#warpperspective))

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. I've got most of it working now, but in order to align it correctly, for #5 wouldn't I want to invert the estimated transformation to correct the perspective. Frame 1 establishes correct perspective, and the homography matrix is the transform to get from Frame 1 to Frame 2. To get Frame 2 aligned with Frame 1, we should apple Inv(M) on Frame 2. Thanks again, please let me know if I'm misunderstanding something

Comment: Yes it is perfectly possible. It actually depends on the flags you use for `warpPerspective`, but I think you got this right.